# How to integrate XERO in ios APP

Tags: ios, xero-api

I would like to know is there any SDK for XERO to integrate in to an iOS app.

If there is, what is the process?
I would like to share images(e.g. some bill images) to XERO from my
app

I can't find any API links for iOS and it would be helpful if anyone can
give me any information about XERO integration in iOS.

Comment: Just type "Xero API" into Google and you will find - https://developer.xero.com/

Comment: so Direct SDK Not available For this Right??and can u tell me how to communicate with Xero ??

Comment: I don't think they have a framework for iOS. It looks like a standard RESTFull service

Comment: as per my requirement i need to upload image to xero  which one should i choose pulic or private  when adding APP

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but as of now xero has changed oAuth 1.0 to oAuth 2.0 and they have provided a correct way to do the integration with mobile and desktop clients using PKCE.
https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/pkce-flow/

though there are not good sample code available in Swift iOS. so i have has published an article with sample code and downloadable git repository. i hope it helps you or anyone looking for iOS integration with xero.

https://satvasolutions.com/latest-guide-on-oauth-2-0-integration-with-native-ios-app-using-pkce/

Hope this helps.